data is not showing on UI screen what is error in my program plz ans if any know this what mistake i m doing in this
JS::
import { LightningElement,track, wire } from 'lwc';
import fetchPatientData from '@salesforce/apex/PatientData.fetchPatientData';
export default class SalesforceCommandFile extends LightningElement {
    @track Username ='Prashant Sontakke';
     @track searchInput;
     searchInput;
     HandleSearchValue(event)
     {
        console.log('i m in handle search value');
        console.log('event',event);
        console.log('search value is==',event.target.value);
        this.searchInput=event.target.value;
 
     }
     @wire(fetchPatientData,{ searchInput: '$searchKey' }) lstofdatarecords;
 
}

HTML::
<template>
    <div class="slds-p-top_xx-small">
       <lightning-card>
           <div class="slds-p-top_x-small">
           <lightning-tabset variant="scoped">
               <lightning-tab label=" Search">
                   <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small">Enter your Search Here!</h1>
                   <br>
               <lightning-input name="enter-search" label="Enter your Patient Data" type="search" onchange={HandleSearchValue}></lightning-input>
             <br>
                <h2>Search value is:{searchInput}</h2> 
                <div>{lstofdatarecords}</div>
            </lightning-tab>
               <lightning-tab label="Hospital">
                   Two Content !
               </lightning-tab>
               <lightning-tab label="Patient">
                   Three Content !
               </lightning-tab>
           </lightning-tabset> 
            </div>
           <div class="slds-p-top_x-small">
            Welcome Mr:{Username}
            <br>
            Here is your search Resultt!
               </div>
           </lightning-card>
       </div>
   </template>

APEX::
public class PatientData {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static list<patients__c> fetchPatientData(string searchkey)
    {
        string searchkeyval= searchkey+'%';
      list<patients__c> lstPatient=new list<patients__c>([select id,Name_of_Patient__c,Country__c,State__c from patients__c 
                                                             WHERE Name_of_Patient__c like:searchkeyval]);
        system.debug('lstPatient=='+lstPatient.size());
         system.debug('lstPatient=='+lstPatient);
        return lstPatient;
    }

}



You have declared searchInput twice in your JavaScript file.
In your @wire service, you're using searchInput: '$searchKey', but searchKey is not defined anywhere in your code. You should use searchInput: '$searchInput' instead.
To display the data from lstofdatarecords, you need to iterate over the records using a template loop. Also, make sure you're accessing the correct property from the wire service. It should be lstofdatarecords.data.

JS::
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import fetchPatientData from '@salesforce/apex/PatientData.fetchPatientData';

export default class SalesforceCommandFile extends LightningElement {
  Username = 'Prashant Sontakke';
  searchInput = '';

  HandleSearchValue(event) {
    this.searchInput = event.target.value;
  }

  @wire(fetchPatientData, { searchKey: '$searchInput' })
  lstofdatarecords;
}

HTML::
<template>
        <div class="slds-p-top_xx-small">
                <lightning-card>
                        <div class="slds-p-top_x-small">
                                <lightning-tabset variant="scoped">
                                        <lightning-tab label="Search">
                                                <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small">Enter your Search Here!</h1>
                                                <br>
                                                <lightning-input name="enter-search" label="Enter your Patient Data" type="search" onchange={HandleSearchValue}></lightning-input>
                                                <br>
                                                <h2>Search value is: {searchInput}</h2>
                                                <template if:true={lstofdatarecords.data}>
                                                <div>
                                                        <template for:each={lstofdatarecords.data} for:item="patient">
                                                                <p key={patient.Id}>{patient.Name_of_Patient__c}</p>
                                                        </template>
                                                </div>
                                                </template>
                                        </lightning-tab>
                                        <lightning-tab label="Hospital">
                                           Two Content !
                                        </lightning-tab>
                                        <lightning-tab label="Patient">
                                           Three Content !
                                        </lightning-tab>
                                </lightning-tabset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-p-top_x-small">
                                Welcome Mr: {Username}
                                <br>
                                Here is your search Result!
                        </div>
                </lightning-card>
        </div>
</template>

APEX::
public class PatientData {
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static list<patients__c> fetchPatientData(string searchkey) {
                string searchkeyval = searchkey+'%';
                list<patients__c> lstPatient=new list<patients__c>([select id,Name_of_Patient__c,Country__c,State__c from patients__c 
                                                                     WHERE Name_of_Patient__c like:searchkeyval]);
                system.debug('lstPatient=='+lstPatient.size());
                system.debug('lstPatient=='+lstPatient);
                return lstPatient;
        }

}


Applied but still not working plz correct it
